# $0=\frac{13+13^2+13^3+\cdots}{1+2+3+\cdots}$ using infinite sums?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

**This is not homework, just curiosity.**

My question arose from the apparent absurdity that $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$, even though $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}$ only makes sense when $Re(z)>1$.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n, \lvert{x}\rvert < 1$. It is known that $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Let us now take the value of $f$ when $x=13$ (which also *makes sense* in the same way that taking $z=-1$ *makes sense*). We then have:

$$f(13) = \frac{1}{1-13}=-\frac{1}{12},$$ and consequently 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 13^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n,$$
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 13^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n,$$
$$1+\frac{13+13^2+13^3+\cdots}{1+2+3+\cdots}=1,$$ and finally
$$\frac{13+13^2+13^3+\cdots}{1+2+3+\cdots}=0.$$

Basically the idea is that in the case of $\zeta$, the LHS sum was divergent for the chosen parameter while the RHS was convergent, in the same way that in the case of $f$, the LHS diverged while the RHS was allowed to converge.

So, why does the above happen?

Comment: If you put together two pieces of nonsense, you get nonsense out the other end. This should not be surprising.

Comment: Why can you take the $1$ out of the numerator?

Comment: I extracted the n=0 term from the sum to obtain 1.

Comment: Putting $z=-1$ and making *sense* is different thing. One can use Taylor series to argue about $z=-1$, while I don't know any way to make sense out of $z=13$.

Comment: @Integrator This is what I meant. $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}n^x=1+\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}n^x$$ since $$n^0=1.$$

Comment: Where do you get the first equality that uses summations?  I see no intuitive reason that one should have $\sum x^n = \sum n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in going from
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 13^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$$
to
$$1+\frac{13+13^2+13^3+\cdots}{1+2+3+\cdots}=1.$$
You divided the right side by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$, but on the left side you only divided the second term by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$, and you forgot to divide the $1$ by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$. If you do this step correctly, you get
$$\frac1{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n}+\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty13^n}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n}=1,$$
that is **(correcting a big mistake in my original answer)**, 
$$-12+\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty13^n}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n}=1.$$

Comment: How about the part where he said that $1/(1-13) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 13^n$? Or the part where he used that $-1/12 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n$?

Comment: I didn't intend for my comment to be hostile, only to note that a long list of things the OP did were nonsense. (This leads to your last line being nonsense too, since you assumed some nonsense to get there; but if their beginning nonsense were right, then it'd be right.) I'm not your downvoter.

Comment: @MikeMiller (and also @ the irresponsible, indolent downvoters) The "identities" $\sum_{n=0}^\infty13^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac1{12}$ are not the OP's mistakes; the credit or blame for them belongs to geniuses like Euler and Ramanujan. The OP, if I read him right, was not **advocating** for those identities; he had seen them somewhere, found them implausible, and was trying for a *reductio ad absurdum*. The OP's error was not in assuming the truth of the identities he was trying to refute, that's standard procedure. But he made a simple algebraic error, which I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: My answer did not discuss the broader issues of the validity or significance of such identities, because I lack the relevant expertise to do so, and because that wasn't the question.